# how to parse json data to mootools javascript?

Tags: json, parsing, mootools

im using mootools.

before i getting this json data

```
{"id":"120","name":"bassara","year":["1999","2003"],"cc":["2.4","2.5","3.0"],"type":"4","trans":["1"],"wd":["1","3"],"fuel":["1","2"],"hand":["1"],"hybrid":["1"]}
```

in javascript

```
function get_cdata(){
var jsonRequest = new Request.JSON({
url: 'ajax_model_info.php?cid=' + cid,
onSuccess: function(car){
(car.id.[1],car.name.[1],car.year.[1])
}
}).send();
}
```

its ok. but now i have to get data from this json

```
[{"7":{"1":0}},{"7":{"2":0}},{"7":{"3":0}},{"10":{"1":0}},{"10":{"2":0}},{"3":{"1":0}},{"3":{"2":0}},{"3":{"3":0}},{"3":{"4":0}},{"5":{"1":0}},{"5":{"2":0}},{"5":{"3":0}},{"5":{"4":0}}]
```

how to get data like first example. because its easy. sorry for noob question.

Answer (score 2):

this is just like any other array of objects you need to iterate.

```
var data = 
[{"7":{"1":0}},{"7":{"2":0}},{"7":{"3":0}},{"10":{"1":0}},{"10":{"2":0}},{"3":{"1":0}},{"3":{"2":0}},{"3":{"3":0}},{"3":{"4":0}},{"5":{"1":0}},{"5":{"2":0}},{"5":{"3":0}},{"5":{"4":0}}];

data.each(function(obj){
    // mootools iterator
    Object.each(obj, function(val, key){
        console.log('key is: ' + key);
        // inner loop again or
        // or standard js iterator
        for (var k in val){
            if (val.hasOwnProperty(k)){
                console.log(k, val[k]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Mootools gives you lots of tools for working with Objects and Arrays - read the manual for both Types methods here: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Object and http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Array

Useful ones here may be pluck, Object.keys, Object.values etc. many ways to approach.

Keep in mind that numeric properties of objects are not covered by FIFO in the spec and Chrome (webkit) tends to sort them and produce them in the wrong order.